# Get All posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post

Below is the code I am using to get all posts in Wordpress, but somehow I am not able to get more than 9 post. I have total of 30 posts. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong.

```
$post_ids = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'sample','fields' => 'ids'));

   if ($post_ids->have_posts()):
     foreach( $post_ids->posts as $id ):
       $post_titles[] = apply_filters('the_title', get_the_title($id));
     endforeach;
  endif;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the posts per page argument of the WP_Query object like so:

```
$post_ids = new WP_Query(array(
   'post_type' => 'sample',
   'fields' => 'ids',
   'posts_per_page' => -1
));
```

By setting `posts_per_page` to `-1` your loop will return all posts. If this argument is not supplied the number of posts will default to the posts per page setting in Reading -> Settings.